# Excel Power Query Number to Text

Tags: json, excel, powerquery

I'm trying to parse a json file but the file is set up in a strange way that excel is having problems deciphering. Please see code example below.

```
"in_network":
[
        {
            "negotiation_arrangement": "ffs",
            "name": "CT Scan",
            "billing_code_type": "X",
            "billing_code_type_version": "2022",
            "billing_code": "XXXX",
            "description": "CT Scan",
            "negotiated_rates": [
                {
                    "provider_references": [
                        380.39
                    ],
                    "negotiated_prices": [
                        {
                            "negotiated_type": "percentage",
                            "negotiated_rate": 4.00,
                            "expiration_date": "9999-99-99",
                            "service_code": [
                                "99"
                            ],
                            "billing_class": "Ultra",
                            "billing_code_modifier": []
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "provider_references": [
                        380.6
                    ],
                    "negotiated_prices": [
                        {
                            "negotiated_type": "percentage",
                            "negotiated_rate": 2.00,
                            "expiration_date": "9999-99-99",
                            "service_code": [
                                "99"
                            ],
                            "billing_class": "Ultra",
                            "billing_code_modifier": []
                        }
                    ]
                }
]
```

There is a field called provider_references, that power query is reading as a number data type. This field has some rows with the entry 380.6 and some rows with an entry of 380.60.  Excel is reading both 380.6 and 380.60 lines as 380.6. . I tried to change the data type in Power Query Editor to text, thinking this would solve the problem, but excel is still not able to differentiate between the two entries and continues to lump the 380.6 and 380.60 Group_IDs together.  Is there a way to ensure that any slight differences in the provider_references field gets captured when parsing the json file?

This is how the json file should be parsed

| provider_references | Negotiated_type | negotiated_rate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 380.60 | percentage | 2.00 |
| 380.60 | percentage | 2.00 |
| 380.6 | percentage | 2.00 |
| 380.6 | percentage | 2.00 |

But this is how power query is actually parsing the file

| provider_references | Negotiated_type | negotiated_rate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 380.6 | percentage | 2.00 |
| 380.6 | percentage | 2.00 |
| 380.6 | percentage | 2.00 |
| 380.6 | percentage | 2.00 |

```
{
    "reporting_entity_name": "test",
    "reporting_entity_type": "testr",
    "last_updated_on": "2022-05-05",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "provider_references": [
        {
            "provider_group_id": 380.1,
            "provider_groups": [
                {
                    "npi": [
                        9999999999
                    ],
                    "tin": {
                        "type": "ein",
                        "value": "57-999999999"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "in_network": [
        {
            "negotiation_arrangement": "ffs",
            "name": "test",
            "billing_code_type": "RC",
            "billing_code_type_version": "2022",
            "billing_code": "xxxx",
            "description": "test",
            "negotiated_rates": [
                {
                    "provider_references": [
                        380.61
                    ],
                    "negotiated_prices": [
                        {
                            "negotiated_type": "negotiated",
                            "negotiated_rate": 0.00,
                            "expiration_date": "9999-12-31",
                            "service_code": [
                                "22"
                            ],
                            "billing_class": "institutional",
                            "billing_code_modifier": []
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "negotiation_arrangement": "ffs",
            "name": "test",
            "billing_code_type": "RC",
            "billing_code_type_version": "2022",
            "billing_code": "zzzz",
            "description": "test",
            "negotiated_rates": [
                {
                    "provider_references": [
                        380.60
                    ],
                    "negotiated_prices": [
                        {
                            "negotiated_type": "negotiated",
                            "negotiated_rate": 105.00,
                            "expiration_date": "9999-12-31",
                            "service_code": [
                                "22"
                            ],
                            "billing_class": "institutional",
                            "billing_code_modifier": ["00"
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
        
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Excel is not able to differentiate between the two entries, because the JSON is not putting the item in quotes to make it a label and it is evaluated as a number

I can't get that sample to evaluate properly as valid JSON. Assuming you can, this probably will work for you.  It adds the leading and trailing quotes to the row below [the row that contains **provider_references**]

```
let  Source = Lines.FromBinary(File.Contents("C:\temp\a.json"), null, null, 1252),
p=List.Transform(List.Positions(Source), each 
    if _ =0 then Source{_} else 
    if Text.Contains(Text.From(Source{_-1}),"provider_references") then """" & Text.Trim(Text.From(Source{_}))& """"  else Source{_}
),
newJson=Json.Document(Text.Combine(p,"#(lf)"))
in newJson
```

Comment: I added the cod. There is no error but the json file just runs and runs and never loads

Comment: Post a link to the contents of the real json file. The snip you provided does not evaluate as a JSON, nor did the one in your last question. That once was missing {} .  I can't figure out what's wrong with this one

Comment: For what it's worth... I added a { at the very start and a } at the very end of J.Price's JSON, and used horseyride's M code, and it worked fine.

Comment: Oh... and I changed the 380.39 in J.Price's JSON to 380.60 to ensure both 380.6 and 380.60 were in there before I used it.

Comment: @MarcPincince thanks. Not sure why I couldn't get it working even with the {} but I thought it would work

Comment: I cant import the entire file due to proprietary reasons but this is a condensed version of what the entire files looks like.

Comment: I added the condensed version under the original block of code.  This should be evaluate as JSON.  When I try to apply your code to this json data structure, the code just run and runs and never loads the file into excel.

Comment: I think the issue is that horseyride's code searches for provider_references and then changes what immediately follows it to text. That worked fine with your originally provided JSON extract because a number was there. But your new extract is different and has a { there, followed by provider_group_id the first time. If you can skip the provider_group_id, try changing horseyride's code to `if Text.Contains(Text.From(Source{_-1}),"provider_references") and Text.Trim(Text.From(Source{_})) <> "{" then """" & Text.Trim(Text.From(Source{_}))& """"  else Source{_}),` to make it not make the { text...

Comment: ...If you cannot skip the provider_group_id, you'll need to work out something similar to what horseyride did to change its number to a text.

Comment: See your other question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72252848/json-file-not-loading-with-power-query/72253016  But Marc has the right answer.  Your sample data does not match your final data in several ways so the code written for sample data does not work