# Add quotes around numbers in Json file in power query

Tags: json, excel, regex, powerquery

I have a json file that needs to be parsed but I have to convert a specific column from number to text before power query evaluates the file.  I have to do this because this particular column being in a number format is causing power query to evaluate some of the records incorrectly.

I was able to get the below listed code from someone on stack overflow as a suggestion of how this conversion could be done.

```
let  Source = Lines.FromBinary(File.Contents("C:\temp\a.json"), null, null, 1252),
p=List.Transform(List.Positions(Source), each 
    if _ =0 then Source{_} else 
    if Text.Contains(Text.From(Source{_-1}),"provider_references") then """" & Text.Trim(Text.From(Source{_}))& """"  else Source{_}
),
newJson=Json.Document(Text.Combine(p,"#(lf)"))
in newJson
```

However, when I run this code the JSON file never loads to excel.   It just keeps running and running.  I'm guessing it's stuck in an infinite loop but since I'm unfamiliar with power query I'm unable to debug.  Any suggestions would be great. Thanks

See structure of json file below

```
{
    "reporting_entity_name": "test",
    "reporting_entity_type": "testr",
    "last_updated_on": "2022-05-05",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "provider_references": [
        {
            "provider_group_id": 380.1,
            "provider_groups": [
                {
                    "npi": [
                        9999999999
                    ],
                    "tin": {
                        "type": "ein",
                        "value": "57-999999999"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "in_network": [
        {
            "negotiation_arrangement": "ffs",
            "name": "test",
            "billing_code_type": "RC",
            "billing_code_type_version": "2022",
            "billing_code": "xxxx",
            "description": "test",
            "negotiated_rates": [
                {
                    "provider_references": [
                        380.61
                    ],
                    "negotiated_prices": [
                        {
                            "negotiated_type": "negotiated",
                            "negotiated_rate": 0.00,
                            "expiration_date": "9999-12-31",
                            "service_code": [
                                "22"
                            ],
                            "billing_class": "institutional",
                            "billing_code_modifier": []
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "negotiation_arrangement": "ffs",
            "name": "test",
            "billing_code_type": "RC",
            "billing_code_type_version": "2022",
            "billing_code": "zzzz",
            "description": "test",
            "negotiated_rates": [
                {
                    "provider_references": [
                        380.60
                    ],
                    "negotiated_prices": [
                        {
                            "negotiated_type": "negotiated",
                            "negotiated_rate": 105.00,
                            "expiration_date": "9999-12-31",
                            "service_code": [
                                "22"
                            ],
                            "billing_class": "institutional",
                            "billing_code_modifier": ["00"
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
        
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puts quotes around any number starting with 380, to convert to a string

```
let Source = Lines.FromBinary(File.Contents("C:\temp\a.json"), null, null, 1252),
fnRegexExtr=(text,regex)=>Web.Page("<script>var x='"&text&"';var y=new RegExp('"&regex&"','g');var b=x.match(y);document.write(b);</script>")[Data]{0}[Children]{0}[Children]{1}[Text]{0} ,
p=List.Transform(List.Positions(Source), each 
if Text.Contains(Source{_},"380") then 
Text.Replace(Source{_},fnRegexExtr(Source{_},"380\.?[0-9]*"),""""&fnRegexExtr(Source{_},"380\.?[0-9]*")&"""")
else Source{_}
),
newJson=Json.Document(Text.Combine(p,"#(lf)"))
in newJson
```

Comment: The JSON files we have to parse were designed by another department.  For some reason, they have two separate files embedded in one JSON file and the structure for each is completely different.  We have to convert both provider_group_id and provider_references columns to text so any column with 380.x has to be converted. No other column with a numerical value needs to be converted but those two. Sorry for the confusion.